# Deferred type inference for inherited class method

Tags: c#, inheritance

What I'm trying to do, without success, is a method on a base class that, using reflection, would update properties defined into inherited classes. So, starting from a specific method like this

```
/** fill the item from a xml node
 */
public TblItem FromXML (XmlNode itemNode)
{
    foreach (XmlNode itemField in itemNode) {
        Type myType = this.GetType ();
        PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty (itemField.Name);
        if (myPropInfo != null) {
            myPropInfo.SetValue (this, Convert.ChangeType (itemField.InnerText, myPropInfo.PropertyType), null);
        } else {            
            throw new MissingFieldException (string.Format ("[Fieldname]wrong fieldname: {0}", itemField.Name));
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

I need it to be defined in a base class called i.e. **TblBase**, containing no properties at all, and being used seamlessly in all the derived classes, i.e. **TblDerived1: TblBase** etc. in which there are different properties defined for each of them, so I'm here asking: is there a way to do that or it is just a dream of my dirty mind?
BTW, this is how I need to use this stuff:

```
    xmlDoc.Load (XMLDbPath); 
    XmlNodeList itemNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes (nodes2select);
    //Tblitem inherits TblBase
    TblItem ti = new TblItem ();
    foreach (XmlNode itemNode in itemNodes) {
        print (((TblItem)ti).FromXML (itemNode).ToString ());
    }
```

Comment: What is not working with the code you have?  If the return type is `TblBase` is seems like it should work at first glance.

Comment: the problem is I don't even know how to change the method declaration to work - I tried something like this **public T FromXML<T> (XmlNode itemNode)** and then changing the return like this **return (T)this;** but the compiler complained **Cannot convert type `TblBase' to `T'**

Comment: Your return type could just be `TblBase` - the caller would have to cast to the right subtype but it should work.  As a side thought - does this method _belong_ in the base class?  Should a class have a method that loads its proerties from XML os should that be a separate class (which would solve your `return (T)(this)` compiler error.

Comment: as suggested by you and Alioza I tried the obvious but doesn't work becase of Getproperty is using the this op which appears to be resolved inside the base and not the inherited class, therefore do not find any property of the latter class.

Comment: It's probably not working because you're not using properties. For field data members use GetField not GetProperty. I will edit my answer to include this detail.

Comment: @DStanley thankyou for your time man, all is up and working - the obvious way was as good as you and Alioza said, case closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code using generics below, I replaced the xml node with a name and a value so I could test.

```
  public T FromXML<T>(string name, string value) where T: TblBase
            {
                Type myType = this.GetType();
                PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(name);
                if (myPropInfo != null)
                {
                    myPropInfo.SetValue(this, Convert.ChangeType(value, myPropInfo.PropertyType), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new MissingFieldException(string.Format("[Fieldname]wrong fieldname: {0}", name));
                }
                return (T)this;
            }
```

And calling it:
var result = yourItem.FromXML(someName, someValue);

### But, it will work without generics as well:

```
    public TblBase FromXML (XmlNode itemNode)
{
    foreach (XmlNode itemField in itemNode) {
        Type myType = this.GetType ();
        PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty (itemField.Name);
        if (myPropInfo != null) {
            myPropInfo.SetValue (this, Convert.ChangeType (itemField.InnerText, myPropInfo.PropertyType), null);
        } else {            
            throw new MissingFieldException (string.Format ("[Fieldname]wrong fieldname: {0}", itemField.Name));
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

and calling it:
TblItem result = (TblItem)yourItem.FromXml(...);

### Edit:

This will work on **properties** (with get and set). If you have field data members you want to change in the same way, you need to use GetField instead of GetProperty:

```
var myFieldInfo = myType.GetField(name)
...
myFieldInfo.SetValue (this, Convert.ChangeType (itemField.InnerText, myFieldInfo.FieldType));
```

Comment: I admit I ain't thought this easy solution but I would've been surprised if it would've worked - as a matter of fact the code branch into the MissingField excedption so appears that **this** belongs to the base class

Comment: It will work if you actually have properties with getters and setters.

Comment: I assure you my child classes have all properties configured like this: public int Id { get; set; }

Comment: Then, maybe there is something different in the name you retrieve from the XmlNode? It must be exactly the same, no spaces, no other characters. Could you provide a sample of the itemNode?

Comment: you got me man - I triple checked and found an hideous typo inside the html. You have my gratitude and upvote sir, thankyou.